# How can I convert my private key from bitaddress.org to WIF without putting the key into a website or a programme?

Tags: electrum, paper-wallet, wallet-import-format

Rule number 1 says: don't put your private key into any website or programme, unless you're performing a transfer. This way you won't be robbed.

Then, I want to "sweep" my money off a paper wallet from bitaddress.org, but Electrum wants me to put the private key in WIF format ( https://bitcoinelectrum.com/sweeping-your-private-keys-into-electrum/ ). How can I convert my key to WIF without breaking the rule number 1?

By the way, what's the name of the format bitaddress.org returns private keys in? It is base58?

Comment: I am able to import private key in Electrum from https://bitaddress.org without changing anything

Answer (score 1):

bitaddress.org already provides your private key in [Wallet Import Format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format), which is encoded in [base58check](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding) format.

In the example screenshot below, the base58check-encoded WIF private key is `KzNKqwBPaVehsA2F94n9UJ5mrkM9NazBjqBBwsb2U9pAGLdc4md3`

To address your "rule 1", the most secure way to handle this data is load Electrum onto an [airgapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_%28networking%29) machine, enter the private key into that secure computer, and then use it to sign a transaction you build with an "online" machine that has access to the UTXO set and your wallet address.

[image: bitaddress.org example]

**Warning: Do not use the key or address in this example for any reason at all besides looking at it and learning! Pasting private keys on websites is always a terrible idea.**

Comment: Hmm, OK, I wasn't exact enough. What I did on the website, after moving my mouse randomly etc., I clicked "paper wallet" and then chose "BIP38 encrypt" and put a password. And then I received a "Encrypted Private Key (Password required)" and it's not what Electrum is asking for... What should I do in order to have this key in WIF format?

Comment: OK, I've found it! Here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92864/priv-key-with-58-characters-to-wif Thank you!